# Load image from folder in solution?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to load an image from a folder in the solution, but I only get a error message that it's not found. What have I done wrong? The code below is in the MainForm.cs that is at the same level as the Resource folder. Help is preciated! Thanks!

```
 // Images
 Image imageCircle = Image.FromFile("Resources/circle.png");

 // Set deafult picture on start
 pictureBox1.Image = imageCircle;
```

Comment: Depends what kind of application it is. Anyway, project root relative path (`~/Resources/circle.png`) is a good start. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It always take the path from the where executable is located(bin folder). So if you can access it using full path, problem will solved. Or you can have a configuration item for the root folder. then access like `Image.FromFile(rootFolder+ "Resources/circle.png");`. Anyway this issue wont be there when you deploy it.

And if you are using resource file,

```
<projectName>.Properties.Resources.<ImageName>;
```

will return the image.

Comment: I'm confused! Should I have both a Resource folder in the solution explorer and a Resource folder /bin/Debug/Resource !? It seems like it works when I used this line of code: Image imageCircle = Image.FromFile("Resources/Circle.png");

Comment: Hope you read the answer properly. if you are using resource file second option is fine for you. but if you need to place it inside the folder, use configuration option to store application path or put the resource directory within the same level of executable when you run the application

Answer (score 17):

*Edit: Fixed Broken Links*

Take a look at this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bka19x4(v=vs.100).aspx), it discusses Adding and Editing Resources and what your options are, and this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht9h2dk8(v=vs.100).aspx) discussing Linked and Embedded resources using the [Resource Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9za7fxc7).

[image: Project Properties Resources]

Then select your file

[image]

Then you can access it like Madurika suggests.

i.e.

```
Image imageCircle = YourPojectName.Properties.Resources.YourFileNameHere;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the images, but to add images are not the problem. The problem is to get them to work in the code. I have tested this and it's still not working:  Image imageCircle = Universal Calculator.Properties.Resources.Circle.png;

Comment: @3D-kreativ It works if you add them the way that I showed, I tested before I posted. If you add them the way that I suggest you will get intellisense showing its availibility you also do not need to use the file extension. added another Image :)

Comment: It's not my day today! Something happend, I got some strange error message, and then I lost all my controls int the form!! But I had a backup that I can work with now :) When I use this line of code: Image imageCircle = UniversalCalculator.Properties.Resources.Circle; I get a red line under Properties!?

Comment: @3D-kreativ Try adding your image from the Project -> properties -> resources page again, or add a .resx file to your project and add your images to that, then you can address it as `Resource1.ImageName` or whatever the name of the Resource file is

Comment: The MSDN articles referenced in this answer are no longer available.  Would suggest updating it with the new references.

Comment: @downvoter if you downvoted because of the broken links, they are fixed

Answer (score 0):

The program is executed in bin/debug (the place where all .dll's are), put the `Resources` folder there.

Comment: But why not in a folder in the solution?

Comment: Well, the dll's are the compiled stuff where and once the project is executed, it is launched from these .dll's - that's where your program is. If you are going to give someone some working software, you wouldn't include the source, would you? You give the working compiled files. For example, imagine every time opening Visual Studio, it would first compile itself :P

Comment: This is just a task for a assignement and it's not going to be a working software outside VisualStudio, but if it was, then I understand that a folder at that location is better, but just for some images should work from the solution, but I have also tested to put a folder like you vrote, but it still can't find it!?

Comment: If you execute the program, it is already working outside VS. And it is not using the source - it uses compiled files and thus it "exists" in the folder which VS set for you, and that is bin/debug. I do not have VS at my hand at the moment, so I am not 100% sure where the location for the image is exactly, but it should be in bin/debug of your solution.